# How to use _.groupby() and import _ using lodash-es

Tags: vuejs3, lodash

I recently used
`import { keyBy } from 'lodash-es';`
in my code.Similarly I also want to import _ for using _.groupby() in lodash.

I am confused on how to use _.groupby() using lodash-es.

I tried using

`import { _ } from 'lodash-es';`

Here is my output:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/lodash-es.js?v=afbadbd5' does not provide an export named '_'

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like below:

```
import * as _  from 'lodash-es';
```

Comment: Can we just import the groupBy function alone from loadash-es?

Comment: yes, import { groupBy } from 'lodash-es'; this way or just import globally & use using _.groupBy()